# Extract a message from the exception through Regular expression

Tags: regex

I got an exception 
"*Unrecognized field rsvName (Class com.alcatel.tpapps.solutionapi.common.RuleSystemVersionRequest), not marked as ignorable*"

I want to extract just a portion of it i.e. '*Unrecognized field rsvName'* just before this pattern "*(Class*".

So what will be the regular expression to extract only "*Unrecognized field rsvName*"?

Comment: does it need to be a regex? what language are you using? In this case it may be easier to find the first occurrence of the string "(Class" and use a substring operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out in which format your exception messages are. If there are always in the format "readable message (exception type), additional info" and only want to extract the readable message, then you could do something like this:

> (.*)\s+(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^[^(]+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF5dE9/1)**

And if you want to capture the content, use capturing groups like this:

```
^([^(]*)\s
or another regex like:
^(.*?)\s\(
```